# Is there a way to change a local user account password on a remote Windows 2008 Server/Windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have to setup an embedded standalone CIFS server outside of domain environment. I shall refer to the server as `storage_gateway`.

The default password setting for the Administrator account is "*Password must be changed*". Until the Administrator password is changed, other local accounts are disabled.

While the server is on default password, connecting to a share fails with NT_STATUS_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE error.

```
   $ smbclient -L //storage_gateway -U Administrator
   session setup failed: NT_STATUS_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE
```

(I have a mixed Linux/Windows environment and prefer smbclient for diagnostics).

To change the password in Windows 2003 Server I could press CTRL-ALT-DEL to get into the *Windows Security* window and change password for the remote server specifying the server name or ip address (xx.xx.xx.xx) in the system password change dialog.

[image: Windows 2003 password change dialog]

(the name `root` is just an example, I have edited the screenshots to translate them from a local language version)

However in Windows 2008 the corresponding dialog lacks the **Log on to** field.

[image: Windows 2008 password change dialog]

Is there a way to change a remote password in Windows 2008 Server/Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting the IP address of the server before the username, e.g.: if you where trying to change the password for an account on 192.168.1.1 you would put:

192.168.1.1\root

oldpassword

newpassword